# pick paragraphs from xml_Nodes in R

Tags: html, r, xpath

I am new to html scraping and R, so  this is a tricky problem for me. I have an html structure specified like below ( only body part). I have to separate sections, each with x number of paragraphs. What I want is to pick out all paragraphs in section1 to one object, and all paragraphs in section 2 in one object.

My current code looks like this:

```
docx <- read_html("Page.html") 
sections = html_nodes(docx, xpath="//div [@class='sections']/*")
```

This gives me an `xml_nodes` object, List of 2, that has the paragraphs within. My problem then is that I cannot use `xpathApply` to a nodeset because it throws an error. But I want to pick out all the paragraphs like this:

```
subsparagraphs1 = html_nodes(sections[[1]], xpath="//p "),
```

but it then picks out all paragraphs from the WHOLE html page, not the first section.

I tried to be more specific:

```
subsections = html_nodes(sections[[1]], xpath="./div/div/p")
```

then it picks out nothing, or this:

```
subsections = html_nodes(sections[[1]], xpath="/p [@class = 'pwrapper']")
```

which also results in nothing. Can anyone help me get around this problem?

best, Mia

This is the html structure I have where I want Text1, text 2 and text 3 save in one object and 4,5 and 6 save in one object.

```
   <div class = "content">
        <div class = "title"> ... </div>
        <div class = "sections"> 
            <div> ... >/div
                <div class = "sectionHeader">
                <div> 
                    <p class = "pwrapper"> Text 1 </p>
                    <p class = "pwrapper"> Text 2 </p>
                    <p class = "pwrapper"> Text 3 </p> 
               </div>
                <div> ... </div>
                <div> ... </div>
            <div> ... >/div
                <div class = "sectionHeader">
                <div>  
                    <p class = "pwrapper"> Text 4 </p>
                    <p class = "pwrapper"> Text 5 </p>
                    <p class = "pwrapper"> Text 6 </p>
                </div>
                <div> ... </div>
                <div> ... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: add point before`xpath=".//p "`

Comment: subsections = html_nodes(sections[[1]], xpath=".//p")  yields nothing

Answer (score 0):

Even if your input XML contains syntax errors, I will presume that the **`sectionHeader` elements are siblings** (they are on the same level under the same parent (`sections`).

In that case, your XPaths will be:

- `//div[@class = 'sections']//div[@class='sectionHeader'][1]//p[@class = 'pwrapper']/text()`
- `//div[@class = 'sections']//div[@class='sectionHeader'][2]//p[@class = 'pwrapper']/text()`

All that varies is **the index** into the `//div[@class='sectionHeader']` sequence (1 and 2 – XPath starts with 1, not 0).

Please let me know if the structure of the input XML is different than what I observed/assumed.

P.S.: You may **simplify** the XPaths by removing the first path portion: `//div[@class = 'sections']`.